# writing a .bat file to create a desktop shortcut that paths to chrome.exe

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, batch-file

I'm trying to write a .bat file to deploy with PDQ and need it to get the target path of chrome.exe installed on the computers and then set that path in a newly created shortcut. what I have right now is this.

```
@echo off

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > CreateShortcut.vbs

echo sLinkFile = "%PUBLIC%\Desktop\ShortcutName.lnk" >> CreateShortcut.vbs

echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> CreateShortcut.vbs

echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" >> CreateShortcut.vbs

echo oLink.Arguments = "internal web app" >> CreateShortcut.vbs

echo oLink.IconLocation = "C:\Users\logo_400x400_xyi_icon.ico" >> CreateShortcut.vbs

echo oLink.WindowStyle = "3" >> CreateShortcut.vbs

echo oLink.Save >> CreateShortcut.vbs

cscript /nologo CreateShortcut.vbs

del CreateShortcut.vbs
```

I know on newer installs of chrome that the path changes to Program files not (x86). So what I want is to be able to determine the path of chrome and then put that path in the shortcut.

Comment: `reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe"` and parse the output

Comment: How would I do that I'm not that proficient with scripting to really understand how to parse the output to the oLink.TargetPath command

Comment: if /i exist "%programFiles% (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" Set "ChromePath=%programFiles% (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
if /i exist "%programFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" Set "ChromePath=%programFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
if not Defined ChromePath goto :Error